# Is there any way to send an Outlook appointment without wrapping an email around?

Tags: java, email, outlook, appointment

Is it possible to send a generated ICS file (with `iCal4J`) diretly to a Outlook calendar without wrapping an email around the ICS. In normal, the ICS file will be attached to the mail and then the mail will be send (using `JavaMail API`). The user then has to open up the appointment and import it into the Outlook calendar.

Is there any way to send the appointment directly, so you got the options to accept or decline an appointment instead of opening the ICS from within a normal mail?

Answer (score 1):

An E-Mail consists of headers (From, To,...) and the actual text. If you can produce such an invitation with Outlook, you could try sending an invitation from Outlook to itself. At the core, it's still an E-Mail, but it has some special headers set.
That way you can examine the SMTP headers added by Outlook to indicate the invitation. Then you adapt your code to add those headers instead of only attaching an ICS file.

Since I don't know (1) if Outlook can send/accept the kind of invitation your looking for and (2) if so, the specific headers used for that, I can not tell you how to do that in detail.

This RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047 suggest there is some format to send a "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST" in addition to a tex/html part. Not sure if that's what Outlook does.